# Clearing records in HBase table

Tags: import, hbase, truncate

We are creating a Disaster Recovery System for HBase tables. Because of the restrictions we are not able to use the fancy methods to maintain the replica of the table. We are using Export/Import statements to get the data into HDFS and using that to create tables in the DR Servers.

While Importing the data into HBase table, we are using truncate command to clear the table and load the data fresh into the table. But the truncate statement is taking a long time to delete the rows. Is there are any other effective statements to clear the entire table?

(truncate takes 33 min for ~2500000 records)

Answer (score 0):

disable -> drop -> create table again, maybe ? I don't know if drop takes too long.

Comment: Actually truncate does the same operations of disabling the table first,drops and creates it again... but I am not sure why it is taking such a long time to truncate the data